# CSS Tables on Mobile

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have very long tables.
Now all my content is coming from tinyMCE and my users don't know about those td and td's. So 90% of my tables don't have th.

Example:

```
<table class="table-small">
<tr>
<td><strong>Application Date</strong></td>
<td><strong>Reference</strong></td>
<td><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>Description</strong></td>
<td><strong>Ward</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06/11/2014</td>
<td>069611</td>
<td><a href="#">International Shop</a></td>
<td>Premises Licence Lost, Stolen, Damaged or Destroyed</td>
<td>Central</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>04/11/2014</td>
<td>070393</td>
<td><a href="#">Liquid</a></td>
<td>Temporary event notice</td>
<td>Central</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>03/11/2014</td>
<td>070382</td>
<td><a href="#">Peterborough Regional College</a></td>
<td>Temporary event notice</td>
<td>Park</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>03/11/2014</td>
<td>070384</td>
<td><a href="#">Pool Hall</a></td>
<td>Temporary event notice</td>
<td>Central</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Anything that you  can propose, since all the examples I have looked up at use `<td>`.

Comment: Have you considered using bootstrap?

Comment: whats your question? "90% of my tables don't have td" but they do in the code you've posted? what is it you need help with?

Comment: 3 recommendations: 1) Switch from table layouts to CSS layouts; 2) Adopt RWD principles to enable your layouts to be cross-platform compatible; 3) Ditch tinyMCE. It's a woefully inadequate, horribly outdated piece of software.

Comment: @atmd i meant they don't have th.

Comment: Bootstrap also uses the principle of th.
@Rounin can't ditch tiinyMCE, client's requirements

Comment: @Rounin "Switch from table layouts to CSS layouts" but it's clearly a table of data. that's what tables are for

Comment: @atmd - yes, you're absolutely right. I wasn't paying enough attention to what was contained in the table cells! My mistake, do keep the `<table>`, @Ali!

Comment: @Ali - yes, I've had a client like this before who insisted on tinyMCE. It's difficult to know how to explain to such a client: "Look, I'm sorry, but you simply don't have the authority to insist on the tools / software / frameworks to be used - because that authority would necessarily stem from a level of professional comprehension which you've just demonstrated you lack. In short, if you're not doing the work, and you're not capable of doing the work, you don't get to decide the toolset."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question.

You want to have responsive tables for mobile users?
If that is the case use `width:100%` on table and `word-wrap: break-word` on td's

Comment: nah mate, it wouldn't work, I already tried it way back - http://prntscr.com/65tblg

Comment: then your only option is to set `overflow:scroll;` to table so users on mobile devices can scroll or go with the floating divs and media queries :)